# Why would the below If statement not work in Python?

Tags: python

```
import requests #for working with APIs
import json #for working with the output of the APIs
import pandas # for working with data frames and reading a csv
import os #for working with directories
import time #pause the loop for 1 second, so that our API call does not get timed out
import sqlite3 #because the API calls are expensive, once we have received information we store it in a sql lite db file, and we will generate the file from there



conn=sqlite3.connect("PhysicianSpecialty.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT distinct PhysicianNPI from PhysicianSpecialty")
IsPhysicianInDBSet=set(list(cur.fetchall()))
print(len(IsPhysicianInDBSet))


physicianlist=["1992952816","1255433801","1861704249"]

for physicianid in physicianlist:
    if str(physicianid) in IsPhysicianInDBSet:
        print("No Need of Api Call")
    else:
        print("Will need a API call")
```

the SQLite DB table has a list of NPIs and their Specialty. I am getting that into a set, and while iterating through an input physicianlist want to check if I already have that information locally, as opposed to going to the API call. In the above case only the else part is executing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you `print(IsPhysicianInDBSet)`?

Comment: Since we cannot see what is inside the set we cannot possibly know what is going wrong.

Comment: I think the set is storing the values as tuples, and I am comparing string to a tuple, when I do a print(IsPhysicianInDBSet) I get values like ('123456789'),('123678945')

Comment: Is the IsPhysicianInDBSet actually a list of tuples? In this case its would be because your comparing a string to a tuple (never going to be truthy)

Or is IsPhysicianInDBSet actually a list of ints? Never going to be truthy because strings are not ints

Comment: When I created the table from where I pulled the values into the set, that column is a text, so the output of the select * from table that is housed into the IsPhysicianInDBSet is a list of tuples, each holding one value. I was hoping i could iterate through that set by doing something like this but no luck   if any(str(physicianid) == str(item) for item in IsPhysicianInDBSet):

Answer (score 1):

The elements of your list are singleton tuples:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('select "foo" union select "bar"').fetchall()
[('bar',), ('foo',)]
>>> 'foo' in _
False
```

Your fetch should probably look more like this:

```
result = [row[0] for row in cur]
```

Or as a set:

```
result = set(row[0] for row in cur)
```

Comment: Thank you Josh, your recommendation helped

Answer (score 0):

Either your physician ID isn't what you think it is or your physicianlist isn't, because fundamentally it works. You need to add some print statements to your lists to ensure they are as you expect.

```
physicianlist=["1992952816","1255433801","1861704249"]

>>> str(1992952816) in physicianlist
True
```